# use htaccess to show page in folder that doesn't exist

Tags: .htaccess

On my website, I have a user profile php file, where if you write `http://www.youdomain.com/user.php?id=[user id]`, it shows that user's profile with that id.

Is there a way in htaccess that if a write `http://www.youdomain.com/users/[user id]`, it will display the page `http://www.youdomain.com?id=[user id]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)/$ /user.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ /user/$1/ [R]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your a life saver. Also can I use this twice in the htaccess folder?

Comment: if you want to use this for diferent links just add rewriterule lines before </ifmodule>